# Что будет если добавить include в .gitignore git submodules

Tags: c++, git, gitignore, git-submodule

Я использую текстовый редактор с функцией управления git репозитория и там очень много коммитов из-за подключенных библиотек (qt, curl, boost-asio) и из-за того, что репозиторий пока не настроен.
Исходники библиотек размещаются в отдельной папке "include". Хотелось бы, чтобы тот, кто будет клонировать репозиторий с github`а, видел, какие библиотеки являются сабмодулями, но чтобы сначала github вообще пропустил такой большой по весу(из-за библиотек) репозиторий.

**Если добавить папку "include" или её содержимое в gitignore, будут ли существовать такие вот ссылочные файлы?**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ничего непонятно. *"там очень много коммитов"* Там = где? Почему это проблема? *"Исходники библиотек размещаются в отдельной папке "include""* В смысле сабмодули лежат в той папке? *"чтобы сначала github вообще пропустил такой большой по весу(из-за библиотек) репозиторий"* В смысле из-за жирных сабмодулей? Сабмодули ничего не весят для гитхаба, это просто ссылка на другой репозиторий и номер коммита в нем.

Comment: "Сабмодули ничего не весят для гитхаба, это просто ссылка на другой репозиторий и номер коммита в нем" - спасибо за ответ